# Show equivalence corresponding Nulls of function.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-writing

I'd like to show that the following two propositions are equivalent:

(1) $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ has a multiple Null, so it's $\ge 2$.

(2) $f$ and $f'$ have a common Null, whereas $f'$ describes the derivative of $f$.

$(1) \to (2)$

If $f$ has a multiple Null/Zero, then $\exists r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}[x] \backslash 0$ so that

(1.1) $f = (x - r)^2 \cdot s$  [I'll proof this later]

Then it is $f' = 2(x-r) \cdot s + (x-r)^2 \cdot s'$

Thus $f'(r) = 0$.

$(2) \to (1)$

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ be the common Zero/Null.

We then have a definite $s \in \mathbb{R}[x] \backslash 0$ with

$f = (x-r)\cdot s$ and follows $f' = s + (x-r)\cdot s'$.

I know want to show: we have a specific form of $s$ so that $s = 0$ because of $r$ being the zero. Something like $ s = (x-r)\cdot s_2$ ?!

---

I hope that both steps are okay so far. If there are any problems, please tell me.

Now (1.1) and its proof:

Let $k \in K$ be a Zero of $f \in K[t]$, then there exists a specific $g \in K[t]$ so that
$f = (t- k)\cdot g$.

Proof: Do a division with remainder for $f$ divided by $(t-k)$. There are now specific $g,r \in K[t]$ with $f = (t-k)\cdot g + r$ and $deg r < deg (t-k) = 1$.

Therefore $r = a_0, a_0 \in K$.

Since $f(k)=0$ we put in $k$ and get $0 = (k-k)\cdot g(k) + r = 0 + a_0$,

so $a_0 = r = 0$.

This is what I wanted to show.

Comment: Maybe someone can tell me what I've done wrong or give any hints?